# How to configure Location directive for different context URI

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

**what is happening:**

Im using following nginx.conf file for load balancing. web application is up and running on nginx 8080 port and able to access the landing page. however, when moving from landing page to "signup" page, it is throwing error.

**what is expected:**

nginx load balancer should redirect the load to the page as mentioned in the Location directive. but that is not happening.

**nginx file :**

```
events {

}

http {

upstream 3.121.253.126 {
    server 3.121.253.126:8080;
    server 3.121.253.126:8080;
    server 3.121.253.126:8080;
 }
  error_log /etc/nginx/error_log.log warn;
  client_max_body_size 20m;

  proxy_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache keys_zone=one:500m max_size=1000m;

  server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name 3.121.253.126;
    root /etc/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    location /signup {
      root /etc/nginx/html;
      index add-user.html;

    #  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/signup;
    #  proxy_set_header Host $host;
   #   rewrite ^/welcome(.*)$ $1 break;
    }

  }

}
```

here is the error log:

> 2019/02/21 09:07:42 [error] 6#6: *510 recv() failed (104: Connection
>   reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   127.0.0.1, server: 3.121.253.126, request: "GET /signup HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/signup", host: "localhost:8080",
>   referrer: "http://3.121.253.126:8080/" 2019/02/21 09:07:42 [warn] 6#6:
>   *510 upstream server temporarily disabled while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 3.121.253.126,
>   request: "GET /signup HTTP/1.0", upstream:
>   "http://127.0.0.1:8080/signup", host: "localhost:8080", referrer:
>   "http://3.121.253.126:8080/" 2019/02/21 09:13:10 [error] 6#6: *1
>   open() "/etc/nginx/html/signup" failed (2: No such file or directory),
>   client: 157.33.175.127, server: 3.121.253.126, request: "GET /signup
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "3.121.253.126:8080", referrer:
>   "http://3.121.253.126:8080/" 2019/02/21 09:15:57 [error] 6#6: *3
>   open() "/etc/nginx/html/signup" failed (2: No such file or directory),
>   client: 157.33.175.127, server: 3.121.253.126, request: "GET /signup
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "3.121.253.126:8080", referrer:
>   "http://3.121.253.126:8080/"

as per log, it is expecting signup html file. however, i am instructing it to use the add-user.html file. not sure why this is not happening.

please suggest

Comment: To be clear, you are instructing Nginx to use a file located at: `/etc/nginx/html/signup/add-user.html`. Where is the file located?

Comment: file is located at : /etc/nginx/html/add-user.html.  so then what should be there in Location directive ?

Comment: file is located at : /etc/nginx/html/add-user.html.  so then what should be there in Location directive ?. why i mentioned /signup because in the web URL of the application , /signup is the context URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to point the URI `/signup` to the file located at `/etc/nginx/html/add-user.html`

There are a number of ways to achieve that using Nginx, including the `rewrite` and `try_files` directives.

For example:

```
location /signup {
    try_files /add-user.html =404;
}
```

The `root` directive does not need to be repeated within this `location` block, as it will inherit the same value from the surrounding block.

The `=404` does nothing as `add-user.html` always exists, but `try_files` requires two parameters. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

The above location will process any request that begins with `/signup` (e.g. `/signup/` or `/signups`).

To restrict it to the single URI `/signup` use the `=` modifier. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location = /signup {
    try_files /add-user.html =404;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. But does this Logic will still be applied to PostMapping Urls ?? (for ex. : @PostMapping("/adduser"))?